# Read from txt file to hashmap

Tags: java, hashmap

How do I read strings and int(Integer) from a text file and update values in a HashMap? File contains:

Bitoque : 2

Pão (cesta de 2) : 1

blahblahblah : 1

Here is what I have so far:

```
  BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("pedidos.txt"));

    String linha;

    int k = 1;
    String valor = null;
    try {
        while ((linha = buffer.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] Linha = linha.split(":");

            System.out.print(k + "-");
            k++;
            Linha[0] = Linha[0].trim();
            Linha[1] = Linha[1].trim();
            //prod.put(Linha[0], Integer.parseInt(Linha[1]));

            for (int i = 0; i < Linha.length; i++) {
                System.out.println(Linha[i] + " ");
                i++;
                int f = 0;
                if (f > linha.length()) {
                    System.out.println("Não existem pedidos");
                }}}
```

This is my initial HashMap:

```
HashMap<String, Integer> prod = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    prod.put("Queijo de Cabra", 0);
    prod.put("Queijo Fresco", 0);
    prod.put("Pão (cesta de 2)", 0);
    //PRATOS            
    prod.put("Bacalhau à Zé do Pipo", 0);
    prod.put("Bitoque", 0);
    prod.put("Salada de atum", 0);
    prod.put("Salada de Nabiças", 0);
    prod.put("Lasanha de vegetais", 0);
    //BEBIDAS            
    prod.put("Café", 0);
    prod.put("Coca-cola(lata)", 0);
    prod.put("7Up(lata)", 0);
    prod.put("Água do Luso 1.5L", 0);
    prod.put("Água do Luso ", 0);
    prod.put("Vinho da casa 1L (branco)", 0);
    prod.put("Vinho da casa 1L (tinto)", 0);
    //SOBREMESAS            
    prod.put("Bolo de bolacha", 0);
    prod.put("Banana", 0);
    prod.put("Melão", 0);
    //OUTROS            
    prod.put("Pau de canela", 0);
    prod.put("Bagaço", 0);
    prod.put("Pastilhas Gorila", 0);
```

How do I creat categories for the hashmap ?

Comment: Where are you stuck? Show your code.

Comment: What works already? Can you read the lines one by one? Does split get your values? Are you successfully converting the second string to an integer? Have you defined your hash map? have you read the javadoc to find out how to put things in a map?  Show us some code, please.

Comment: If you have already gotten and separated the data, then it sounds like all you need to do is read the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) on how to use a HashMap.

Comment: HashMap.put() perhaps?

Comment: My hashmap starts with 0. And I need to add to hashmap the values in the .txt file.

Comment: I see, so you have a hashmap, and you want to update it with the values from the text file?

Answer (score 0):

Check this out:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map.Entry;

public class main {

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    main m = new main();
}

public void usingMaps() {
    String values = "something: 1";

    String[] parts = values.split(":");
    String key = parts[0].trim();
    Integer value = Integer.parseInt(parts[1].trim());
    HashMap<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

    map.put(key, value);

    for (Entry<String, Integer> entry : map.entrySet()) {
        System.out.println(entry.getKey());
        System.out.println(entry.getValue());
    }
}

public main() {
    usingMaps();
}
}
```

Output:

```
something
1
```

Answer (score 0):

As another approach  you can use easy code . So, simple example will be like next:

test.txt

```
test1:1
test2:2
test3:3
```

Code:

```
Properties properties = new Properties();
properties.load(Main.class.getResourceAsStream("test.txt"));

Map map = properties;

Map<String, Integer> testMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
testMap.put("test0",11);
testMap.put("test00",111);

testMap.putAll(map);

System.out.println(testMap);
```

Result:

```
{test00=111, test1=1, test0=11, test2=2, test3=3}
```

---

EDITED to emulate code you have.

Answer (score 0):

Ohhh! I think I understand your question now: you have initial values in the hashmap, and you want to *modify* the values by the values in the text file, (e.g. if the text file says you have 2 of something you want to increase the count of that something by 2?)

if that's what you want, you are very close:

replace this:

```
//prod.put(Linha[0], Integer.parseInt(Linha[1]));
```

with this:

```
prod.put(Linha[0], prod.get(Linha[0])+Integer.parseInt(Linha[1]));
```

(That's the quick and dirty way - it will fail if you don't initialize the value in the hash map to 0.) You can avoid that by testing for this condition:

```
if (prod.containsKey(Linha[0])) {
    // update value
    prod.put(Linha[0], prod.get(Linha[0])+Integer.parseInt(Linha[1]));
} else {
    // first entry
    prod.put(Linha[0], Integer.parseInt(Linha[1]));
}
```

One advantage of this is you can add new products at any time without modifying the code that initializes your map.

Comment: Thats exactly what I need. But it has an error:
Cannot find symbol
Symbol: mothod contains(String)
Location: variabel prod of type hashmap<String Integer>

Comment: @user3194352 oops -fixed it; should have been `containsKey` (most Java collections have a contains() method, but Map has containsKey and containsValue(). IN your use case, you want containsKey, because you want to know if that product is already in your map.

Comment: Thank you very much. Culd you help me in one mor thing? I need to creat 5 categories, and write on file the values from hashmap on each categorie.

Comment: and other thing it still gives me an error on  `prod.put(Linha[0], prod.get(Linha[0])+Integer.parseInt(Linha[1]));`  : Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at projecto.Projecto.main

Comment: Stack overflow is not a personal ”do your project for you" site. If If this answer answered your original question please accept the answer and post a new question concerning how to write things out in categories, explain what you have tried and what isn't working, and somebody here can help you. If you are encountering a null pointer exception, try printing out the values involved (e.g. print out each line before processing it, print out linha[0] and [1] until you know which value on that line is null. Good luck!